# Cannot connect windows form app to sql: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: c#, mysql, windows, forms

I am trying to connect my program to my MySQL database using UniServer. Uniserver allows me to change the root password whenever I open it, so I set the password to 1414. In my program in app.config I have the code :

```
  connectionString="SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=azmansys;User=root;PASSWORD=1414;SslMode=none;"
         providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

in my phpmyadmin I have the database with the name azmansys but regardless of having the correct root password in my code it still gives me the error : Authentication to host 'localhost' for user 'root' using method 'mysql_native_password' failed with message: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) Exception thrown: 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException' in MySql.Data.dll

any help would be appreciated

Comment: Did you try to replace localhost?

Comment: I replaced localhost with 127.0.0.1 but it didn't make a difference, I read somewhere else about having multiple versions of WAMP installed but I only have one so I don't think that's the issue either.